The value of $\sum_{r=0}^{20} (-1)^{r} {20\choose r}^2 r (20-r)$
The value of $\sum_{r=0}^{20} (-1)^{r} {20\choose r}^2 r (20-r)$
My Solution:
I am using ${n\choose r}=\frac{n}{r} {{n-1}\choose {r-1}}$
$\sum_{r=0}^{20} (-1)^{r} {20\choose r}^2 r (20-r)=\sum_{r=1}^{19} (-1)^{r} \left(\frac{20}{r}\right) \left(\frac{20}{20-r}\right) {19\choose r-1}{19\choose {19-r}}$
$\implies -400\sum_{r=1}^{19} (-1)^{r-1}  {19\choose r-1}{19\choose {19-r}}$
After this I am getting answer as $400{19\choose 9}$ but given answer is $-40{38\choose 9}$
Update: $(1+x)^{19}(1-x)^{19}=\bigg({19\choose 0}+{19\choose 1}x+{19\choose 2}x^2+.....+{19\choose 17}x^{17}+{19\choose 18}x^{18}+{19\choose 19}x^{19}\bigg)\cdot \bigg({19\choose 0}-{19\choose 1}x+{19\choose 2}x^2+.....-{19\choose 17}x^{17}+{19\choose 18}x^{18}-{19\choose 19}x^{19}\bigg)$
Now If I multiply all the term in R.H.S then I get ${19\choose 0}{19\choose 18}x^{18}-{19\choose 1}{19\choose 17}x^{18}+.....+{19\choose 18}{19\choose 0}x^{18}+\text{Some other terms not containing}\\x^{18} $
Since my answer is coefficicent of $x^{18}$ in R.H.S
So we must find coefficient of $x^{18}$ in $(1-x^{2})^{19}$ which is $-{19\choose 9}$
So final answer is  $400\cdot {19\choose 9}$

Your answer if exact ! (+1)

"After this I am getting answer as $400{19\choose 9}$": how? (+1)

@AnneBauval I've added an update for the same

Thank you. Brilliant!
